# Thread-based on Windows Phone 8

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-8

I have some application for iOS and android. And I need port it on Windows Phone 8. We have some abstract thread subsystem, and kernel using threads from this subsystem. All this is C++ code.

The first problem I encountered, that run thread on WP8 aka CreateThread. ThreadPool is not a solution for me because application use thread-based parallelism, not a task-based.

My question is how to start thread on WP8? I thied use .NET Thread class, but it doesn't compiling. May be a do something wrong. Please help me by this.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use threads in your Windows Phone application, using the [System.Threading.Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class. Creating a thread is straightforward, pass the method you want to execute to the constructor of the thread, then start it:

```
public void StartThread()
{
    var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(DoSomething);
    thread.Start();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: If my `DoSomething` method is an async one, how do I pass it to the `Thread` constructor?

Comment: @NiiLaryea If it's an async method, first make sure that it really need to be run in a thread. If it does, then use `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Answer (score 0):

you can initialise thread with a method and then start it like

```
var asd = new System.Threading.Thread(method);
asd.Start();

void method()
{
  // Put your Logic Here .....
}
```